# scala.collection.JavaConversions API : Where is the asScala method?

Tags: scala

I know that if i do a

> import collection.JavaConverters._

I can do a `javaList.asScala`. But on the API documentation of `collection.JavaConverters` I can't find this method (as well as asJava).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JavaConverters](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/27da46343cd545534819300235bc64ab74958c92/src/library/scala/collection/JavaConverters.scala) just mixes two traits DecorateAsJava and DecorateAsScala

```
object JavaConverters extends DecorateAsJava with DecorateAsScala
```

The actual extension methods are defined in these traits. See [DecorateAsJava](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/27da46343cd545534819300235bc64ab74958c92/src/library/scala/collection/convert/DecorateAsJava.scala) and [DecorateAsScala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/27da46343cd545534819300235bc64ab74958c92/src/library/scala/collection/convert/DecorateAsScala.scala) in the [scala.collection.convert namespace](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/27da46343cd545534819300235bc64ab74958c92/src/library/scala/collection/convert).

Here are the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.convert.package) for the scala.collection.convert namespace.

The methods asScala/asJava are defined on specialized decorator classes in [Decorators](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/27da46343cd545534819300235bc64ab74958c92/src/library/scala/collection/convert/Decorators.scala). The various implicit conversion methods produce such decorators. Note that Decorators is private[collection] and does not appear in the API docs.

Comment: I still don't know where the `asScala` method is defined. You don't answer to the question.

Comment: If you follow the links Rüdiger provided, you'll see e.g. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/27da46343cd545534819300235bc64ab74958c92/src/library/scala/collection/convert/Decorators.scala#L17-L26

Answer (score 1):

These methods are defined on [`Decorators.AsJava` and `Decorators.AsScala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/convert/Decorators.scala) which you can see as return types of implicit conversions in `JavaConverters`. They seem not to be documented because it's a `private[collection]` type.